# How can i call a mail function in Root ViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send a mail with attachment . In my app i created a separate class for the mail function and in rootViewController I have button **Email It** . When i click it My mail Function has to be called but it doesn't.

```
  MFMailViewController *controller = [[MFMailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"MFMailViewController" bundle:nil];                


[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

After that i got know that i cant use the mail function like this. can any one help me find this

Comment: try calling it as modalcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not MFMailViewController, its `MFMailComposeViewController`. Please go through this [Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to get more details.

Here is a sample code

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if(mailController!=nil) {
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailController setSubject:urSubject];
            [mailController setMessageBody:urBody isHTML:NO];
            [mailController addAttachmentData:urData mimeType:type fileName:urfileName];
}
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
[mailController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance method in MFMailViewController class with some parameter like dictionary or NSArray

when you click on Email it button you are creating object of MFMailViewController then called the instance method using the controller object and pass the parameter or info to. 
then push it's view to navigation.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

@interface MFMailViewController : NSObject

```
{}
```

-(void)sendEmail:(NSMutableDictionary*)withData;

```
@end
#import "MFMailViewController.h"

@implementation MFMailViewController

-(void)sendEmail:(NSMutableDictionary*)withData;
{
    //definition goes here.................

}
@end

MFMailViewController *controller = [[MFMailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"MFMailViewController" bundle:nil];                

[controller sendEmail:withData];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

simple where you want to send mail just define this code in you method .....
but first define delegate in .h file of your viewController
delegate is `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`
 and then in button click method write this code......

```
       MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setToRecipients:@"Recipients Name"];
        [controller setSubject:@"your subject"];
        [controller setMessageBody:@"Your Text Here for Mail" isHTML:YES]; 
        if (controller)
        {
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            [controller release];
        }
```

and then you can just paste bellow mailComposerDelegate method in yourViewController.m file.....

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error;
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
        NSLog(@"Mail Sent");
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```